# Windows cmd for loop with other commands following it

Tags: windows, shell, for-loop, command-line, cmd

I'm trying to iterate over a set of directories, copy a file from each one if it exists, and then exit. This would be trivial if I did it from a batch script, but I want to be able to type this into the command line, all at once.

However, doing this doesn't work:

```
for [some files] do copy theFile theDestination && exit
```

The first file is copied, and then `exit` runs, killing the terminal.

Is there a way to delimit which commands are run by the for loop? It'd look like this in pseudocode

```
foreach file {
copy(file,dest);
}
exit;
```

The current behavior is more like

```
foreach file {
copy(file,dest);
exit;
}
```

Parentheses didn't help, and I'm having trouble turning up anything else on the subject.

Comment: Why are you using exit at all.

Comment: `(for %A in (*) do Echo %A) & Exit` groups. `Cmd /c for /d %A in (*) Do Echo %A\File.ext`.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I didn't try that. Mind submitting it as an answer? (As for the reasoning, this is a script for a USB Rubber Ducky, which is essentially a keyboard macro)